# Launching another application from my Android application causes issue

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Android application(lets call it as 'Main application') which will launch another application (lets call it as 'Helper application')depending upon the user action.Consider the following scenarion.

1. User A logs into my Main application
2. My Main application launches Helper application with details specific to User A(which is sent as extras in Intent)
3. User A minimizes the Helper application
4. User A logs out from my Main application
5. User B logs into my Main application
6. My Main application tries to launches Helper application with details specific to User B(which is sent as extras in Intent).But it is not newly creating the Helper application.It just brings the previous Helper application to foreground with details of old user A.

I tried to catch the new intent in onNewIntent() but it never gets fired(declared the activity as singleTop in manifest).

My question is how to launch the Helper application every time with the new intent.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There might be bug in your helper app, check that it acts upon the new intent.  If its not your helper app, sad day for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override onPause() method from your Helper application.

Like this :

```
    protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Paused", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          finish();
    }
```

So, whenever your helper application goes in background it will be finished by this piece of code.

And every time you will get your Helper application with the new intent.

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: The thing is i don't want to finish the app when it goes to background.

Comment: I think you can use `SharedPreferences` also in your `Helper Application` by which you can store user details passed in `extras` with `Intent` and you can checked with newly passed user details with that and render view details as per that.

Answer (score 1):

you can solve current issue using SharedPreferences as :

when User B logs into my Main application create a [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) :

```
 SharedPreferences mainPrefs = 
             this.getSharedPreferences("mainappliction", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mainPrefs.edit();
 prefsEditor.putString("user_detailone", "userdetailone");
 prefsEditor.putString("user_detailtwo", "userdetailtwo");
 prefsEditor.commit();
```

and in Helper application every time when application resume read all latest details from `SharedPreferences` and update UI according to latest details of user

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
   SharedPreferences mainPrefs =
         this.getSharedPreferences("mainappliction", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
   String struserdetailone = mainPrefs.getString("user_detailone", "nothing");
   //......

  //update your Helper application UI here according user details
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: If i make it as NO_HISTORY, then my helper application gets finished when it goes to background and it is not possible to launch it from recent list of applications.

Comment: @androidGuy : then what is issue now if you start  helper application  again then it will start with latest Intent

Comment: @androidGuy : i figure out your issue you can try it by using SharedPreferences